1 bit in the file was changed after calling read() function
After executing transmission-create to generate a metainfo file for a folder, some files in the folder was modified. The stat information indicates that only the access time was changed. Additionally, verifying the local folder against the metainfo file failed.
What transmission-create does is traverse the folder, open each file in read-only mode, read a specified size as a piece from each file, calculate the SHA1 hash of each piece, and finally write all SHA1 hashes and other information from memory to the file system.
I modify the source try to find out what happend, see https://github.com/transmission/transmission/issues/6839#issuecomment-2472786410
What isn't mentioned in the github issue are some dmesg logs, see them below.
I think it's a system-level issue, specifically with the ext4 file system, or something wrong with my system, plz help me out.
BUG: unable to handle page fault for address: ffff984057cca1f0
#PF: supervisor read access in kernel mode
#PF: error_code(0x0000) - not-present page
PGD 0 P4D 0 
Oops: Oops: 0000 [#1] PREEMPT SMP PTI
CPU: 0 UID: 1000 PID: 40939 Comm: transmission-da Not tainted 6.11.0-9-generic #9-Ubuntu
Hardware name: ZOTAC MEK1/MEK1, BIOS 5.12 05/03/2018
RIP: 0010:__xas_next+0xb0/0x170
Code: 01 41 88 44 24 12 48 8b 5b 08 49 89 5c 24 18 48 85 db 0f 84 8c 00 00 00 3c 40 74 de 44 0f b6 e8 0f 87 a2 00 00 00 49 83 c5 04 <4a> 8b 44 eb 08 48 89 c2 83 e2 03 48 83 fa 02 75 50 48 3d 00 10 00
RSP: 0018:ffffbce000c039d8 EFLAGS: 00010202
RAX: 0000000000000039 RBX: ffff984057cca000 RCX: 0000000000000000
RDX: 0000000000000000 RSI: 0000000000008e3f RDI: ffffbce000c03a28
RBP: ffffbce000c03a00 R08: ffff98c057cd2920 R09: 0000000000000000
R10: 0000000008e3f000 R11: 000000007ca12f5d R12: ffffbce000c03a28
R13: 000000000000003d R14: 000000000000003f R15: 000000000000003f
FS:  00007c03952006c0(0000) GS:ffff98c13fc00000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
CR2: ffff984057cca1f0 CR3: 00000001063d2005 CR4: 00000000003706f0
Call Trace:
 <TASK>
 ? show_trace_log_lvl+0x1be/0x310
 ? show_trace_log_lvl+0x1be/0x310
 ? filemap_get_read_batch+0x1f4/0x340
 ? show_regs.part.0+0x22/0x30
 ? __die_body.cold+0x8/0x10
 ? __die+0x2a/0x40
 ? page_fault_oops+0x16c/0x180
 ? kernelmode_fixup_or_oops.isra.0+0x69/0x90
 ? __bad_area_nosemaphore+0x18e/0x1e0
 ? default_wake_function+0x1a/0x40
 ? autoremove_wake_function+0x12/0x50
 ? bad_area_nosemaphore+0x16/0x30
 ? do_kern_addr_fault+0x78/0xa0
 ? exc_page_fault+0x1b0/0x1c0
 ? asm_exc_page_fault+0x27/0x30
 ? __xas_next+0xb0/0x170
 ? xas_load+0x17/0x100
 filemap_get_read_batch+0x1f4/0x340
 filemap_get_pages+0xa2/0x3b0
 ? copy_page_to_iter+0x9f/0x180
 filemap_read+0x104/0x490
 generic_file_read_iter+0xbe/0x110
 ext4_file_read_iter+0x63/0x210
 vfs_read+0x2a0/0x380
 __x64_sys_pread64+0xa6/0xd0
 x64_sys_call+0x1aea/0x22b0
 do_syscall_64+0x7e/0x170
 ? handle_softirqs+0xe7/0x340
 ? irqentry_exit_to_user_mode+0x43/0x250
 ? irqentry_exit+0x43/0x50
 ? sysvec_apic_timer_interrupt+0x57/0xc0
 entry_SYSCALL_64_after_hwframe+0x76/0x7e
RIP: 0033:0x7c0398d02035
Code: e8 48 89 75 f0 89 7d f8 48 89 4d e0 e8 04 b8 f9 ff 4c 8b 55 e0 48 8b 55 e8 41 89 c0 48 8b 75 f0 8b 7d f8 b8 11 00 00 00 0f 05 <48> 3d 00 f0 ff ff 77 2b 44 89 c7 48 89 45 f8 e8 57 b8 f9 ff 48 8b
RSP: 002b:00007c03951f8590 EFLAGS: 00000293 ORIG_RAX: 0000000000000011
RAX: ffffffffffffffda RBX: 00007c03951f8660 RCX: 00007c0398d02035
RDX: 0000000000040000 RSI: 00007c0384221740 RDI: 0000000000000011
RBP: 00007c03951f85b0 R08: 0000000000000000 R09: 0000000000000000
R10: 0000000008e2019e R11: 0000000000000293 R12: 0000000000000000
R13: 0000000073bf2dbf R14: 0000000000040000 R15: 0000000001b00000
 </TASK>
Modules linked in: tls snd_soc_avs intel_rapl_msr intel_rapl_common snd_soc_hda_codec snd_hda_ext_core intel_uncore_frequency intel_uncore_frequency_common snd_soc_core intel_tcc_cooling x86_pkg_temp_thermal intel_powerclamp coretemp snd_compress ac97_bus snd_pcm_dmaengine kvm_intel btusb snd_hda_codec_realtek snd_hda_codec_generic snd_hda_scodec_component snd_hda_codec_hdmi nouveau ee1004 btrtl kvm iwlmvm snd_hda_intel btintel mac80211 snd_intel_dspcfg libarc4 snd_intel_sdw_acpi btbcm btmtk snd_hda_codec mxm_wmi snd_hda_core drm_gpuvm drm_exec snd_hwdep iwlwifi gpu_sched bluetooth drm_ttm_helper rapl intel_cstate i2c_i801 ttm snd_pcm drm_display_helper i2c_mux cec snd_timer i2c_smbus snd rc_core i2c_algo_bit soundcore binfmt_misc nls_iso8859_1 intel_pmc_core intel_vsec pmt_telemetry pmt_class acpi_pad mac_hid cfg80211 sch_fq_codel dm_multipath efi_pstore nfnetlink dmi_sysfs ip_tables x_tables autofs4 btrfs blake2b_generic raid10 raid456 async_raid6_recov async_memcpy async_pq async_xor async_tx xor
 raid6_pq libcrc32c raid1 raid0 crct10dif_pclmul crc32_pclmul polyval_generic ghash_clmulni_intel sha256_ssse3 nvme sha1_ssse3 nvme_core xhci_pci r8169 nvme_auth ahci realtek libahci xhci_pci_renesas video wmi aesni_intel crypto_simd cryptd
CR2: ffff984057cca1f0
---[ end trace 0000000000000000 ]---
RIP: 0010:__xas_next+0xb0/0x170
Code: 01 41 88 44 24 12 48 8b 5b 08 49 89 5c 24 18 48 85 db 0f 84 8c 00 00 00 3c 40 74 de 44 0f b6 e8 0f 87 a2 00 00 00 49 83 c5 04 <4a> 8b 44 eb 08 48 89 c2 83 e2 03 48 83 fa 02 75 50 48 3d 00 10 00
RSP: 0018:ffffbce000c039d8 EFLAGS: 00010202
RAX: 0000000000000039 RBX: ffff984057cca000 RCX: 0000000000000000
RDX: 0000000000000000 RSI: 0000000000008e3f RDI: ffffbce000c03a28
RBP: ffffbce000c03a00 R08: ffff98c057cd2920 R09: 0000000000000000
R10: 0000000008e3f000 R11: 000000007ca12f5d R12: ffffbce000c03a28
R13: 000000000000003d R14: 000000000000003f R15: 000000000000003f
FS:  00007c03952006c0(0000) GS:ffff98c13fc00000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
CR2: ffff984057cca1f0 CR3: 00000001063d2005 CR4: 00000000003706f0
note: transmission-da[40939] exited with irqs disabled

# transmission-create -V
transmission-create 4.0.6 (38c164933e)

# lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 24.10
Release:        24.10
Codename:       oracular

# uname -a
Linux ubuntu2204 6.11.0-9-generic #9-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Mon Oct 14 13:19:59 UTC 2024 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

# sudo lshw -class disk
  *-disk:0                  
       description: ATA Disk
       product: WDC WD120EDAZ-11
       vendor: Western Digital
       physical id: 0
       bus info: scsi@2:0.0.0
       logical name: /dev/sda
       version: 0A81
       serial: 8CKM****
       size: 10TiB (12TB)
       capabilities: gpt-1.00 partitioned partitioned:gpt
       configuration: ansiversion=5 guid=********-****-****-****-************ logicalsectorsize=512 sectorsize=4096


Please [edit] your question and show us the actual command you used, and then show us exactly what you did that showed you that the files actually changed. If this information is in the github issue, then reproduce it here so all the information is contained in the question.

Is this reproducable?

What's the question here?
